# Grant daemon process access to read user mail

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token

We have a console app that we want to run on a schedule in the context of **service_account1**.
The app needs to access Outlook account for **service_account2** using Graph API and read incoming emails.

I am trying to figure out the way to access **service_account2** mailbox without requiring user intervention and skipping the consent screen.

One option I see is to manually get authentication code from **/authorize** endpoint by signing in as **service_account2** and consenting to mailbox access by the application. This will give me the authentication code that I can use to get **access_token** and **refresh_token** programmatically and that would do the trick.

Is there a way to programmatically do it without having this initial manual step?

Answer (score 1):

For daemon process/console app where you don't want user to explicitly sign-in, you can use client credentials grant.

You can create an application in Azure AD for your process and then use clientid and client secret to access the required resources. For mailbox your resource would be something like /users/{userPrincipalName}/mailfolders/inbox/messages under the graph api.

Here’s a sample for client credentials grant flow from daemon app - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/blob/master/README.md

Specifically for avoiding an explicit consent part see steps 9, 10 under this link - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/blob/master/README.md#step-2--register-the-sample-with-your-azure-active-directory-tenant.

Steps refer to 'TodoListService' as sample api, but in your case it will be graph I suppose.

> Configure Permissions for your application. To that extent, in the
>   Settings menu, choose the 'Required permissions' section and then,
>   click on Add, then Select an API, and type TodoListService in the
>   textbox. Then, click on Select Permissions and select 'TodoListAdmin'.
>   This will allow this client app to access the service app using
>   TodoListAdmin role.
>
> At this stage permissions are assigned correctly but client app is a
>   daemon service so it cannot accept the consent via UI to use the
>   service app. To avoid this situation, please click on "Grant
>   permissions" which will accept the consent for the app at the admin
>   level.

Comment: Neo99 the Client Credentials flow won't work for me because it will allow daemon app to read mail for any mailbox in a given tenant. I want to restrict it to just a given service account.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but it may help someone. I had a similar situation where I wanted to use a daemon to read from a shared mailbox but admins in my organization were not allowing the Mail.Read permission because of its capabilities to read from all mailboxes. I had to restrict the app to only one mailbox to get the consent from admin.

There is an option to scope the application permission to specific mailbox. This ensures that you are not reading from any other mailbox but only the ones you are allowed to. I used the client credential flow in my daemon.

Check the documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access